# Django textarea widget <p>

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin I am using the textarea widget.

When I save data, it is saved inside a `<p></p>` tag.

I dont want this - any solutions, I just want to get the data out without being wrapped in a `<p>`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a WYSIWYG like TinyMCE or CKEditor?

Comment: just using the textarea widget on its own, no WYSIWYG at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to save it without html coding, but maybe it is enough to you to display without that

. Just put a |safe in the template after the variable name, example:

```
{{ variable|safe }}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs